# Mostrar nombre y no id en columnas de un Filament Source

Tags: php, laravel-10, laravel-filament, filamentphp

Estoy montando desarrollando una plataforma donde requiero mostrar en una tabla el nombre del país.

Cuando doy formato a la tabla me muestra el ID y no el nombre del modelo.

[image: esta es la columna donde quiero mostrar el nombre del país]

Intenté obtenerlo mediante el relationship con institution_country.country_name, pero queda en blanco la columna.

### Este es el código del ¨filament resource¨

```
->columns([
            TextColumn::make('institution_name'),
            TextColumn::make('institution_director'),
            TextColumn::make('institution_country'),
            TextColumn::make('institution_city'),
        ])
```

### Este es el código del ¨model¨

```
protected $fillable = [
    'institution_name',
    'institution_director',
    'institution_phone',
    'institution_whatsapp',
    'institution_address',
    'institution_city',
    'institution_state',
    'institution_country',
    'institution_instagram',
];
```

## **Pregunta:**

¿Cómo muestro el nombre del país en lugar del ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Ya logre solucionarlo!

El problema radica en las ***relations*** que no estaban adecuadamente configuradas.

Les comparto la solución por si alguien pasa por mi mismo problema.

**Institution Model:**

[image: Institution Model]

**Country Model:**

[image: Country Model]

**Institution Resource:**

[image: Institution Resource]

¡Gracias por tu apoyo Goyo!

Comment: Hola Santiago, bienvenido y gracias por tomarte la molestia de publicar tu propia solución, te sugiero, para que no la eliminen, que quites la imágenes, y agregues el código como texto, y si es posible, una breve explicación de como se soluciona el problema, así puede que recibas unos puntitos de reputación, ver [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para evitar votos negativos y/o que tu repuesta sea eliminada, 
aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Answer (score 0):

Actualiza el codigo de tu modelo "Institution" para definir la relación con el país. Asumiendo es uno a uno (belongsTo)

```
// En el modelo "Institution.php"
public function country()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Country::class, 'institution_country');
}
```

Contando con que realmente está obteniendo el resultado adecuado en tu Modelo

Intenta esto

```
TextColumn::make('institution_country.country_name')

// En el modelo "Institution.php"
protected $fillable = [
    // ...
    'institution_country',
    // ...
];
```

Comment: Hola Goyo, Gracias por tu aporte! Intenté lo que propones, pero al actualizar el **Filament Resource** la tabla queda con el campo _Institution Country_ en blanco 

Comment: Pero debes tener algo en el modelo que no permite traerse el valor, voy hacer una edición del código

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario de nuevo. Lo he intentado todo... Pero si aplico lo que me cuentas, sigue quedando en blanco el campo en la tabla.

Comment: Podrías proporcionar la estructura de las tablas "institutions" y "countries"? Es decir, sus esquemas y los nombres de las columnas

Comment: Hola Goyo, te cuento que ya lo solucione... el problema provenía de las relations de los modelos. ¡Afortunadamente! Muchas gracias por tu aporte y tu ayuda.